# Java Multimap<String,String> with Trove

Tags: java, multimap, trove4j

I have a pretty large google `Multimap<String,String>` and was looking into ways to reduce the memory usage.  In all of the examples I can find people are doing something like:

```
Multimaps.newSetMultimap(
TDecorators.wrap(new TIntObjectHashMap<Collection<Integer>>()),
new Supplier<Set<Integer>>() {
public Set<Integer> get() {
  return TDecorators.wrap(new TIntHashSet());
}
});
```

which works for a `Multimap <Integer,Integer>`, is it possible to use Trove to wrap a `<String,String>`?

Incase anyone is interested in the future I went with 
http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/
to write the hash map to the filesystem.

Comment: What is a *google Multimap< String,String >*? You mean Guava's `Multimap`?

Comment: TIntObjectHashMap appears to require int keys, but it doesn't look like there is any requirement for values to be Integers.  Could you use a `Multimap<Integer,String>`, keying on [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()), instead?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your application?  Immutable collections, including multimaps, are significantly more memory-efficient than mutable collections.  Alternately, depending on the sorts of strings you have, it might e.g. be more efficient to store them in a UTF-8 `byte[]`.  Other than those two suggestions, there's not likely to be any other options except maybe a database on disk.

Comment: I'm storing in the Map a timestamp and then a list of keywords. Then I rely on Collections.frequency to count how many times each keyword is used per time period.  I checked out the ImmutableMultimaps via your suggestion (thank you) so hopefully that will help some, hard to tell without going into work....and guava are "several of Google's core libraries" I don't really see a problem calling it googles.

Comment: You should maybe checkout Radix-tree. It's very similar to compressing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trove4j doesn't contain hashmap for string-to-string.

See http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/package-summary.html

Answer (score 6):

Guava's Multimaps are backed by standard JDK Collections which aren't optimized for memory usage. For example, `ArrayListMultimap<K, V>` is backed by `HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>` and `HashMultimap<K, V>` is backed by `HashMap<K, HashSet<V>>`.

[Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections)) has Multimaps backed by its own container types, `UnifiedMap` and `UnifiedSet`. `UnifiedMap` uses half the memory of `HashMap` and `UnifiedSet` uses a quarter the memory of `HashSet`. The memory benefits you'll see will depend on whether you use a `FastListMultimap` or a `UnifiedSetMultimap`.

More detailed memory comparisons are available [here](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/presentations/GSC_Memory_Tests.pdf).

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at memory efficient variant of hash maps, such as this one: https://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/

If your value strings are long enough, compression could be an option. You could also look into disk backed solutions such as Ehcache, depending on your access statistics.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I use is to use `Map<String,Collection<String>>` where the values start out as `ArrayList<String>` and get promoted to `HashSet<String>` when the bucket hits some threshold, say 32 elements.

I have found this saves a lot of memory for small buckets.